# Where did Wizards store their money before Gringotts?

Tags: harry-potter, economics, gringotts

Gringotts was founded in 1474, which raises the question of where wizards and witches stored their wealth before the bank was founded.

Is there a mention of this somewhere within the lore?

Comment: Where did Muggles store their money before 1474?

Comment: The same place Napoleon keeps his armies.

Comment: @Valorum In his sleevies?

Comment: I'm imagining Scrooge McDuck's vault for some reason.

Comment: Perhaps there just isn't a high demand for banking services in the HP world? Even in the modern day, Gringotts doesn't even offer cheque books

Comment: When you can just _accio_ cash from the safe at home, @JayFor, who needs a check book?